# Input form and changing form PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I have made a database and a php to insert new information to the database. When I add some new information, everything works well, but when I want to change these information and update these, my input form look really different. This is my code for adding new information

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Klanten invoeren</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="SEDDopslaan.php" method="post">
      <p>
        Reisnummer: <br>
        <input name="reisnummer" type="text" size="30" tabindex="1">
      </p>
     
      <p>
        Land: <br>
        <select name="land">
        <option value="Nederland">Nederland
        <Option value="Duitsland">Duitsland
        <Option value="Frankrijk">Frankrijk
        <Option value="Belgie">Belgie
        </select>
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Plaats: <br>
        <input name="plaats" type="text" size="30" tabindex="3">
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Vertrekdatum: <br>
        <input name="vertrekdatum" type="date" size="30" tabindex="4">
        
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Retourdatum: <br>
        <input name="retourdatum" type="date" size="30" tabindex="5">
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Aantalpersonen: <br>
        <input name="aantalpersonen" type="text" size="30" tabindex="2">
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Prijs: <br>
        <input name="prijs" type="text" size="30" tabindex="2">
      </p>
      
      <p>
        Betaling voltooid: <br>
        <input name="betalingvoltooid" type="checkbox" value="Ja" size="30" tabindex="2">Ja
        <input name="betalingvoltooid" type="checkbox" value="Nee" size="30" tabindex="2">Nee
      </p>
      
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" title="Verstuur dit formulier" tabindex="6">
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my code for changing information

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Klant wijzigen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
      // Maken van verbinding
      try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Reisbureau','root','');
      }
      catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
      // De SQL opdracht
      // Hier wordt de klant geselecteerd om de gegevens op
      // te halen die je wilt wijzigen. Het klantnummer zit
      // in $_POST[verstopt]
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM boeking WHERE reisnummer = $_POST[verstopt]";
      $resultaat = $db->query($sql);
      // De klantgegevens worden in variabelen gestopt zodat
      // we ze in het formulier kunnen zien
      foreach($resultaat as $row) {
        $reisnummer = $row['reisnummer'];
        $land = $row['land'];
        $plaats = $row['plaats'];
        $vertrekdatum = $row['vertrekdatum'];
        $retourdatum  = $row['retourdatum'];
        $aantalpersonen  = $row['aantalpersonen'];
        $prijs  = $row['prijs'];
        $betalingvoltooid = $row['betalingvoltooid'];
}
      // Sluiten van verbinding
$db = NULL;
      echo "<form action='SEDDwijzigdefinitief.php'method='post'>
        <p>Reisnummer: <br>
        <input name='reisnummer' type='text' size='30'value=$reisnummer tabindex='1'>
        </p>
        <p>Land: <br>
        <input name='land' type='text' size='30' value=$land tabindex='2'>
        </p>
        <p>Plaats: <br>
        <input name='plaats' type='text' size='30' value=$plaats tabindex='3'>
        </p>
        <p>vertrekdatum: <br>
        <input name='vertrekdatum' type='date' size='30'value=$vertrekdatum tabindex='4'>
        </p>
        <p>Retourdatum: <br>
        <input name='retourdatum' type='date' size='30'value=$retourdatum tabindex='5'>
        </p>
        <p>Aantalpersonen: <br>
        <input name='aantalpersonen' type='text' size='30'value=$aantalpersonen tabindex='5'>
        </p>
        <p>Prijs: <br>
        <input name='prijs' type='text' size='30'value=$prijs tabindex='5'>
        </p>
        <p>Betalingvoltooid: <br>
        <input name='betalingvoltooid' type='text' size='30'value=$betalingvoltooid tabindex='5'>
        </p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='submit'value='Verstuur' title='Verstuur dit formulier' tabindex='6'>
</p>
</form>"
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have exactly the same form in "Add information" as in "Change information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code echo's your variables! You need to write like this:

```
echo "<input name='prijs' type='text' size='30'value='" . $prijs ."' tabindex='5'>";
```

So your code will `echo` the data from your database and not the `$prijs` plain as a string!

Hope this will help <3

***Bonus:***

If your `$_POST[verstopt]` should be a string then use single quotes '' in your query!

To pretend MySQL Injection, you could write your query like this:

```
 $verstopt = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[verstopt]);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM boeking WHERE reisnummer = $verstopt";
```

**Change Checkbox value**

You could use Javascript to change the value and then you post trough your `<form>` the input wehre the value is written in. Change the style from your input to `style='display:none;'` so that the user only can see the checkbox and not the `input` one which is gonna be used to send to your mysql query.

```js
function test(){

var Result =  document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
document.getElementById('ResultCheckbox').value = Result;

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="test();">
<input name="checkboxAnswer" id="ResultCheckbox" value="no">
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how do I insert for example a checkbox into this? In "toevoegen" there is a checkbox, so you can select "Ja" or "Nee" at "betalingvoltooid". Is it possible to add a checkbox into this form? So you can change "ja" into "nee" and save this?

Comment: If this worked, please checkmark my answer! I edited my post and adapted it to your question, with that checkbox situation. Hope this helps you out <3

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using delevoper tools of your browser to watch the HTML code?

Also, have you tried using quotes to enter your PHP variables? 
Something like:

```
<input name='reisnummer' type='text' size='30' value='".$reisnummer."' tabindex='1'>
```

What do you mean with form looking "different"?

Comment: I would like to have exactly the same look and working form as when you add new information. So "Edit information" look the same as "Add new information"